# How to extend spark View component and add default controls in it?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, view, extends

How can I extend spark View component so it has default Image and Label control on top? I need it for a mobile app built on Apache Flex and AIR having ten different views which has the same image and label on top.

Comment: Yijie, your edit is not correct, because the question is not connected to Java at all. It is about Apache Flex and Spark components.

Comment: Looking at the tag, the edit is correct, just for the wrong reasons.  Apache Spark refers to a [cluster computing engine](https://spark.apache.org/), not Spark components in Flex.